# Set the title of an SherlockActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I have two activities.

The first one extends SherlockListActivity and the second extends SherlockFragmentActivity.In the first I can set the title and subtitle of my actionBar like this `getSupportActionBar.setTitle("some Title");` and it works fine.

When I do the same on my second Activity the name wouldn't change (I mentioned before the supers of my classes in case it's relevant to the issue).

Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: ok I've just found out what is the problem.I add on my actionBar some tabs so when i try to set the title,it gets hidden(i guess) is there any way i can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The title shouldnt be hidden by default, but you could try using

```
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

to see if you get the title back. or if you are calling that method somewhere with false as a parameter, then that's your problem.